# How will my 1031 boot be taxed?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, capital-gains-tax, 1031-exchange

In the USA I'm working on a 1031 exchange. I'm having trouble finding information on how a boot (if I take one) will be taxed.

I'm closing on my sale for $700k. I will have a capital gain of $550k.
I have a mortgage of $200k.

If I buy something new for $600k, leaving me with a $100k boot, how will that $100k be taxed? I know it *will be taxed* but how much?

Will the entire $100k be a gain? Will that change the capital basis of this new property for future 1031 exchanges?

Comment: If the sale is $700k and the mortgage outstanding is $200k, how did you arrive at a capital gain of $550k?  What did I miss here?  Wouldn't the gain be the difference between sale price and outstanding mortgage?

Comment: I had a mortgage on the property. When I converted it from my residence to an investment the property was under water, so the capital basis for the investment was $150k. Depreciation has changed this a little but I wanted to keep round numbers for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there was a $200k mortgage on the relinquished property, then there is no ['mortgage boot'](https://atlas1031.com/blog/1031-exchange-boot-equity-and-mortgage-boot-explained/), because there is a $200k mortgage on the replacement property.

You have the $100k 'equity boot' as you explained. It is fully taxable at your personal capital gains rate. Federal tax rate calculator [here](https://www.nerdwallet.com/article/taxes/capital-gains-tax-rates). Add your state income tax rate to this federal rate to find your total capital gains tax rate.

You can [avoid an equity boot](https://learn.roofstock.com/blog/1031-exchange-boot) altogether, e.g. if you buy two replacement properties rather than one.

Comment: If the $100k is all gain, does that change my capital basis in the new property?

Comment: Yes, according to this link that uses an example with a $113k gain: "You will have to adjust your basis in the new property down by the amount of the deferred capital gain. Your basis in the new property will now be $200,000 – $113,000, or $87,000." https://tax-lawyer-texas.com/2018/05/28/calculation-of-basis-in-new-property-in-a-section-1031-like-kind-exchange/